# Erlang module compiling

Tags: erlang

I started learning Erlang, after read first chapter got strange error during compilation of module.

So when I try to compile demo.erl

```
-module(demo).
-author("alex").

-export([double/1]).

double(Value) ->
   Value * 2.
```

So I try to compile it

```
1> m(demo).
```

and got

```
** exception error: undefined function demo:module_info/0
```

The only way to compile was

```
make:files(filelib:wildcard("demo.erl")).
```

I got demo.beam and now even after deletion of it m(demo). begin work.

Can anyone explain to me that compiler behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile a module from the Erlang shell, use the `c` command:

```
1> c(demo).
{ok,demo}
```

The shell `m` command is for retrieving information about a compiled module:

```
2> m(demo).
Module: demo
MD5: 422cee9099e136c6dec13dd200927c63
Compiled: December 12 2015, 22:51
Object file: /tmp/demo.beam
Compiler options:  []
Exports:
         double/1
         module_info/0
         module_info/1
ok
```